# Passing static data into React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I want to know how to passs Static (Hardcoded)Values into React Component if it needs Interface, I want simply want to show the layout only not the data, as of now data can be static.

Below is the code where I've to do changes, Code is already there but I'm not sure that how I can pass the data.

```
class News extends CmsComponent<IProps & IStateProps & DispatchProp<any>, {}> {
public render() {
    const {
        newsGroup,
        editMode,
        categoryId,
    } = this.props;

    /** Return isComponentLoaded null if newsGroup is not loaded */
    const isComponentLoaded = ((newsGroup === null) && (categoryId !== null && categoryId !== '-1')) ? null : true;

    return this.renderCmsComponent(newsGroup, editMode, this.renderComponent, isComponentLoaded);
}

private renderComponent = () => {
    const {
        newsGroup,
        control: {
            parameters,
        },
    } = this.props;

    const group = newsGroup.value;
    const hasChildren = (group.children.value.length || group.rssChildren.value.length);

    // Handle early exit if no news items are available. This ensures links don't render when news can be deleted to 0.
    if (!hasChildren || !group.active.value) {
        this.renderEmptyComponent('DoesNotExist');
    }

    const hasCssPropertySupport = CSSPropertyBrowserSupport('--css-vars');
    const classes = classNames(
        Classes.ID.NEWS,
        {
            [Classes.ID.NEWS_IE]: !hasCssPropertySupport,
        },
    );

    const constructedLink = `${group.displayUrl.value}UserNews.aspx`;
    const articles = this.getNews();
    const displayFormat = parameters.values.DisplayFormat || NewsDisplayFormat.Standard;
    const userProvidedHeading = parameters.values.Heading;
    const renderActionLinks = (group.showMore.value || !group.isRSS.value);

    return (
        <div className={classes}>
            {(group.title.value && displayFormat !== NewsDisplayFormat.Carousel) && (
                <ComponentHeadersHelper showBorder={true} text={userProvidedHeading.length ? userProvidedHeading : group.title.value} />
            )}
            {articles}
            {renderActionLinks && (
                <div className={Classes.ID.NEWS_CATEGORY_LINKS}>
                    {group.showMore.value && (
                        <Link href={group.displayUrl.value} title={''}>
                            {group.moreNewsText.value}
                        </Link>
                    )}
                    {!group.isRSS.value && isAllowed(newsGroup.value.permissionValue.value, Permissions.Create) && (
                        <Link href={constructedLink} title={''}>
                            {this.localise(NewsMessage.SubmitArticle)}
                        </Link>
                    )}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

/**
 * Generates list of all news articles for selected group
 */
private getNews() {
    const {
        newsGroup,
        control: {
            parameters,
        },
    } = this.props;

    const articlesArray: JSX.Element[] = [];
    const carouselArticles: NewsArticle.INewsArticle[] = [];
    const group = newsGroup.value;
    const isRss = group.isRSS.value;
    const children = (isRss ? group.rssChildren : group.children);
    const displayFormat = parameters.values.DisplayFormat || NewsDisplayFormat.Standard;
    const userProvidedHeading = parameters.values.Heading;

    const adminNewsLimit: number = newsGroup.value.numOfNewsItems.value;
    const isDefaultNoOfArticles = (parameters.values.NumberOfArticles === 'Default' || parameters.values.NumberOfArticles === '0');
    // if default / 0 is set in cms property dropdown. Use admin setting otherwise use value specified in CMS properties
    let noOfArticles: number = isDefaultNoOfArticles ? adminNewsLimit : parseInt(parameters.values.NumberOfArticles, 10);

    children.value.forEach(article => {
        if (article.isComplete && noOfArticles > 0) {
            if (displayFormat === NewsDisplayFormat.Carousel) {
                carouselArticles.push(article.value);
            }
            else if (displayFormat === NewsDisplayFormat.Headline || displayFormat === NewsDisplayFormat.HeadlinesMultiple || displayFormat === NewsDisplayFormat.HeadlinesSingle) {
                articlesArray.push(
                    <NewsHeadline
                        article={article}
                        key={article.value.id}
                    />,
                );
            }
            else {
                articlesArray.push(
                    <NewsCategoryThumbnail
                        article={article}
                        key={article.value.id}
                        showSummary={group.showSummary.value}
                        showThumbnails={group.showThumbnails.value}
                        category={group}
                    />,
                );
            }
            noOfArticles -= 1;
        }
    });

    if (carouselArticles.length) {
        return (
            <NewsCarousel
                articles={carouselArticles}
                category={group}
                title={userProvidedHeading.length ? userProvidedHeading : group.title.value}
                showSummary={group.showSummary.value}
                isRSS={isRss}
            />
        );
    }

    return articlesArray;
}
```

}

News Carousel IProps

```
interface IProps {
/** category of the news */
title: string;
/** an array of news articles to be rendered */
articles: NewsArticle.INewsArticle[];
/** news category */
category?: NewsGroup.INewsGroup;
/** current cms control that will be rendered */
control?: ICmsControl;
/** If false, don't render the summary text, set via admin setting. */
showSummary?: boolean;
/** If news Feed is RSS news feed. */
isRSS?: boolean;}
```

News Article Interface

```
export namespace NewsArticle {
    export const groupName = 'entities';
    export const itemKind = 'NewsDocument';
export interface INewsArticle extends IStoreData {
    title: Value<string>;
    displayUrl: Value<string>;
    description: Value<string>;
    image: Value<string>;
    createdBy: Value<Profile.IProfile>;
    titleLink: Value<string>;
    openNewWindow: Value<boolean>;
    dateCreated: Value<DateTimeEx>;
    displayDate: Value<DateTimeEx>;
    feedType: Value<string>;
    newsBody: Value<string>;
    parentCategory?: Value<string>;
    folderDisplayUrl?: Value<string>;
    hash?: Value<string>;
    approved: Value<boolean>;
    permissionValue?: Value<number>;
}
```

How do I hard Code the values of   
Can anyone help with this? 
I want to hardcode and pass the data in the frontend.